# Make specific PowerPoint visible/active when more than one open?

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I have a macro that enables a user to select a new PPT to open or choose from ones that are already open and then paste a table from excel into that specific PPT.  I am having an issue where if a user has more than one PPT open and it was not the most recently viewed/visible file, the table will not paste in the correct area.

Is there a way to make the PPT needed visible or active before pasting?  I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Dim pptName As String
Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim slds As PowerPoint.Slides
Dim sld As PowerPoint.slide
Dim shp As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim tbl As Table
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim main As CustomLayout
Dim supp As CustomLayout

Set ppt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

Dim arr() As String
Dim j As Variant

ans = MsgBox("Is the PowerPoint already open?", vbYesNo)

If ans = vbYes Then
    For Each myPres In ppt.Presentations
        ReDim Preserve arr(j)
        arr(j) = myPres.Name
        Debug.Print arr(j)
        j = j + 1
    Next
    DoEvents

    nws.Columns("A:A").Clear

    nws.Range("A1:A" & j) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr())

    wb.Names("Array").RefersTo = "=Array!$A$1:$A$" & j

    Application.Wait (3000)

    'This is where user selects from the currently open PPTs
    With New SetPPT
        .Show
        If Not .Cancelled Then
            pptName = .SelectedFile
            'Application.Wait (3000)
            Debug.Print pptName
            Set myPres = ppt.Presentations(pptName)
            myPres.Application.Visible = True
        End If
    End With

    Unload SetPPT

Else
    MsgBox ("Please choose PowerPoint to open.")
    pptName = openDialog()
    Set myPres = ppt.Presentations.Open(pptName)
End If

myPres.Application.Visible = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I changed the code to the following, including a DocumentWindow and activating it, that solved the issue.

```
Dim pptName As String
Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim slds As PowerPoint.Slides
Dim sld As PowerPoint.slide
Dim shp As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim tbl As Table
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim main As CustomLayout
Dim supp As CustomLayout
Dim wnd as DocumentWindow

Set ppt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

Dim arr() As String
Dim j As Variant

ans = MsgBox("Is the PowerPoint already open?", vbYesNo)

If ans = vbYes Then
    For Each myPres In ppt.Presentations
        ReDim Preserve arr(j)
        arr(j) = myPres.Name
        Debug.Print arr(j)
        j = j + 1
    Next
DoEvents

nws.Columns("A:A").Clear

nws.Range("A1:A" & j) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr())

wb.Names("Array").RefersTo = "=Array!$A$1:$A$" & j

Application.Wait (3000)

'This is where user selects from the currently open PPTs
With New SetPPT
    .Show
    If Not .Cancelled Then
        pptName = .SelectedFile
        'Application.Wait (3000)
        Debug.Print pptName
        Set myPres = ppt.Presentations(pptName)
        Set wnd = myPres.Windows(1)
        wnd.Activate
    End If
End With

Unload SetPPT

Else
    MsgBox ("Please choose PowerPoint to open.")
    pptName = openDialog()
    Set myPres = ppt.Presentations.Open(pptName)
End If

myPres.Application.Visible = True
```